# Data stored in Class extending application returning null

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a data class that extends Application and one of the data sets its supposed to be storing is a HashMap of POI locations and Time visited

```
public class CharacterSheet extends Application {
private HashMap<PointOfInterest, Date> coolDowns = new HashMap<>();

    public HashMap GetAllCoolDowns() { return coolDowns; } //dev only?
    public Date GetCoolDown(PointOfInterest poi) {return coolDowns.get(poi);}
    public Date PutCoolDown(PointOfInterest poi, Date date) {return coolDowns.put(poi, date);}}
```

Then on a google maps activity I grab the OnPOIclick

```
    @Override
public void onPoiClick(final PointOfInterest poi) {

    //POI Cool Down
    Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    Date lastTime = ((CharacterSheet) this.getApplication()).GetCoolDown(poi);//this ONLY returns null??

    if (lastTime != null){
        int timeDiff = currentTime.compareTo(lastTime);
        makeToast("Time Since last visit: " + timeDiff );
    } else { makeToast("First");
        }

    ((CharacterSheet) this.getApplication()).PutCoolDown(poi, currentTime);
    makeToast("This?" + ((CharacterSheet) this.getApplication()).GetCoolDown(poi));}
```

The order should be Click poi, Get current time.. get last time visited, if last time is null.. never been before, store time and date in a hashmap with poi as key

Next time turn up and this time last time should not be null as we stored this poi and time already.. but no matter what it returns null..

Last line of code is a makeToast helper telling me what is in the Data Class.. this gives me a date value of when I clicked not a null value

There is a fragment generated later on in the OnPOIClick, but still before the user can do anything, which you end up looking at and have to "back" out  of, I don't know how this could effect it as all the code is finished before even calling for data for the fragment but feel It should be mentioned

```
        PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);
    String placeId = poi.placeId;
    List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.TYPES);
    FetchPlaceRequest request = FetchPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeId, placeFields);

    placesClient.fetchPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FetchPlaceResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FetchPlaceResponse fetchPlaceResponse) {
            Place place = fetchPlaceResponse.getPlace();
            PlaceDataHolder holder = new PlaceDataHolder(place);
            String placeName = poi.name;
            makeLootFragment(holder,placeName);
```

The Fragment launched is the entire point of clicking the POI so if this is the case I'll need to think of another way of handling the cooldowns.. but I really don't see why it would interfere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not being thoughtful enough about the PointOfInterest that was returned. It comes with a UUID for every time the request is made, rendering it useless as a key as every time I clicked it changed.. this was discovered by changing my post operation check from making sure it had gone into the hashMap, to seeing the contents of the entire hashMap, soon saw that the entries where building up despite only clicking one poi

To solve this was simple enough. I created a new String variable from poi.name and used that in place of the poi, had to change the HashMap to accept a String rather than a PointOfInterest